# Ember isn't loading some images in production

Tags: javascript, heroku, ember.js

I have an Ember-cli 1.13 app that has a lot of images stored in the public directory.  Now, it will correctly load all images except those in a particular component.

The component is called like this:

```
{{list-item url="list-url" name="List Name" price="240"}}
```

Internally, the component is this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/{{url}}">
  <img src="/{{url}}.png" alt='Picture of the {{name}}' />
  <p class="item-name">{{name}}</p>
  ...
</a>
```

When I build the application and launch to heroku the broken path is

```
https://ridiculous-name-123123.herokuapp.com/list-item.png
```

Which is the same as the localhost path except with a different domain obviously.

All of the other images work when not used with components.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build with a production env your assets undergo something called [fingerprinting](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls).

What appears to be the problem here is that your "built" url links to the un-fingerprinted file, one solution would be to move these images into a folder and exclude them from being fingerprinted, in your `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    exclude: ['myComponentImages/']
  }
});
```

A better solution would be to have the full url or pass a class that changes the image displayed since it looks like these are static assets and not user uploaded content.

Comment: Thank you, this is great and I didn't know Ember was doing this.

Comment: How would  you go about getting the fingerprint if you want to reference it in javascript? Is there a function that returns the adjusted filename (e.g. `Ember.getFingerprint('/assets/asdf.png')` returns something like `/assets/asdf-80938294jjx809sf.png`)?

Comment: Could we get some clarification on `['myComponentImages/']` ... and an example path?