# emberjs: dynamic image don't from html img tag

Tags: image, ember.js, dynamic

Hi Im trying to add dynamic image from public stored image. It work perfect in development but shown issue in deployment after build.

template.hbs

```
<img src="image/draw-info/{{iconname}}.png" alt="{{iconname}}">
```

after build an image is generated with {{imagename}}-{{someidentifier}}.png but html tag search for {{imagename}}.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember isn't loading some images in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471219/ember-isnt-loading-some-images-in-production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of adding `someidentifier` to assets in production builds is called *[fingerprinting](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls)*.

As mentioned in the linked documentation, you can turn it off in your `ember-cli-build.js` by disabling it for png files entirely or by excluding certain patterns, e.g. if all your iconnames start with `icon`, this should do:

```
fingerprint: {
  exclude: ['icon'],
}
```